# Excel VBA Pivot Table Filter Hide

Tags: vba, excel, filter, pivot-table

I am currently making a dashboard which uses pivot tables and slicers to pull through the data.
When I add the pivot table excel displays all of the fields which I am using as the 'report filter'. When I then come to arrange my data I am unable to put tables closely together (as they can not overlap) and have to hide all of these fields from the users view.

Does anybody know any VBA which could simply be used to hide the report filter from appearing in the actual body of the workbook itself? So I can then display tables closely together?

That would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Hide the rows they sit on?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Excel 2010 or later, then here's a way, with no VBA necessary: Don't add those those fields to the Report Filter area. Instead, add Slicers for those fields, put them somewhere out of site, and use those Slicers to filter the PivotTable instead.